# Ajax unit testing mocking using Jack

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I am using Jack as JavaScript mocking library. http://github.com/keronsen/jack . I am also using qunit.

I have following AJAX call in my javascript code which I am tring to write test for.

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#advance_search_form').attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: parameterizedData,
    success: function(json) {
        APP.actOnResult.successCallback(json);
    }
});
```

Following code is working.

```
jack(function() {
    jack.expect('$.ajax').exactly('1 time');
}
```

However I want to test if all the arguments are properly submitted. I tried following but did not work.

```
jack.expect('$.ajax').exactly('1 time').whereArgument(0).is(function(){
```

var args = arguments;
  ok('http://localhost:3000/users', args.url, 'url should be valid'); 
  // similary test for many keys of object
  });

I want to get hold of arguments so that I could perform a battery of test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches:

Use .hasProperties():

```
jack.expect('$.ajax').once()
    .whereArgument(0).hasProperties({
         'type': 'post',
         'url': 'http://localhost:3000/users'
    });
```

... or capture the arguments and make qunit assertions:

```
var ajaxArgs;
jack.expect('$.ajax').once().mock(function() { ajaxArgs = arguments[0]; });
// ... the code that triggers .ajax()
equals('http://localhost:3000/users', ajaxArgs.url);
```

The first version uses more of the Jack API (that deserves better documentation), and is more readable, IMO.

The latter version will give you much better error reporting.

Comment: Take two minutes to add both the approaches to README of jack. once again good job with jack. I love it.

Comment: first approach is working. Second approach is failing. Both arguments and arguments[0] are reporting as undefined.

Comment: Strange. Try replacing the function part with 
function(a) { ajaxArgs = a; }

Comment: Yeap that did it. passing a to the function solved the problem. Thanks a bunch.